# npm old project doesnt install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to run a project written with an older version of npm in 2019. In the user manual its written that I have to run "npm insall" to install the project, but I have the new version npm 8.3.1 installed with new node version 16 and it has many errors. I tried to downgrade my npm to v4 or v3 but after when I want to install I have error:

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! argv "C:\programs\node.exe" "C:\Users\AndiaFathi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v16.14.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

````
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp64\www\vocsensuimanager\npm-debug.log```
````

I tried to solve this error by deleting the npm and cash-npm in C:\Users\AndiaFathi\AppData\Roaming and force cleaning the cash but It will take back the npm version to 8.3.1 and again the same problem. I have also tried to find an older version of node to come directly with an older version of npm but I couldnt find the installer file. Can you pleas tell me what am I doing wrong?